# The following code to check if a file exists on a server does not work

Tags: c#

I found the following code to check if a file exists on a server, but is not working for me.  It tells me that "test1.tx" does not exist even though the file exists and its size is 498 bytes.
If I try with Ftp.ListDirectory it tells me that the file does not exist.
If I try with Ftp.GetFileSize it does not provide any results and the debugger's immediate gives me the following message: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll.

Using "request.UseBinary = true" does not make any difference.

I have posted this same question at this link:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/89e05cf3-189f-48b7-ba28-f93b1a9d44ae

Could someone help me how to fix it?

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ftpServerIP = txtIPaddress.Text.Trim();
        string ftpUserID = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
        string ftpPassword = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "//tmp/test1.txt");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            //request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
            //request.UseBinary = true;

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Okay.
                textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                textBox1.AppendText("File exist");
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Response != null)
            {
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (response.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
                {
                    // Directory not found. 
                    textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                    textBox1.AppendText("File does not exist");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks very much,
xplorer2k

Comment: Have you checked the message of the exception object?

Comment: You've specified ListDirectory, but you've pointed to a file ?

Comment: These are the error messages:
Using WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory:
"File does not exist"
The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).


Using WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize:
The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized.

Thanks,
xplorer2k

Answer (score 1):

Escape characters in C# are defined with a "\" character, so I think there shouldn't be a problem with the single-slash before the filename, however, I would not say the same from the double-slash following the ftpServerIP variable in the string. To make sure, type it as you would normally using the the at sign.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"ftp://{0}/tmp/test1.txt", ftpServerIP));
```

Comment: It returnes the same message with either GetFileSize or ListDirectory:

File does not exist

Message out of IF block: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

I added one more line on the catch block:

                        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                        textBox1.AppendText("File does not exist");
                    }
                }
                //else
                textBox1.AppendText("Message out of IF block: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }

Comment: Hi Will,
I tried the several methods of WebRequestMethods.Ftp.xxx and the only ones that work are DeleteFile, DownloadFile and UploadFile all the others ones fail as before. xplorer2k

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to an FTP server you might specify the Uri as "ftp//ftp.domain.com/somedirectory" but this translates to: "ftp://ftp.domain.com/homedirectoryforftp/somedirectory". To be able to define the full root directory use "ftp://ftp.domain.com//somedirectory" which translates to //somedirectory on the machine.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The ftp server was automatically redirecting to the directory I had specified in the url (e.g. ftp://ftp.domain.com/somedirectory") so when I tried to list the directory it returned a 550 for ftp://ftp.domain.com/somedirectory/somedirectory. The fix was to strip the directory from the url in the request i.e. ftp://ftp.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

which line does the error occur on when you try ftp.getfilesize?

Comment: It happens at this line (with both ListDirectory or GetFileSize):
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())

Thanks,
xplorer2k

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you do if you want to delete a file atleast. Would imagine you could just 
change it from DeleteFile to GetFileSize.

Are you sure your network credentials are set up correctly, meaning could there be anything
wrong with the strings that are passed along as your username and password ?

```
if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
{
    return false;
}
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Delete status: {0}",response.StatusDescription);  
response.Close();
return true;
```

Comment: User name and password credential are correct as they work with explorer or mozilla browsers. Thanks,
xplorer2k

Comment: As I mentioned above, I tried several methods of WebRequestMethods.Ftp.xxx and the only ones that work are DeleteFile, DownloadFile and UploadFile all the others ones fail as before.  Therefore username and password are fine.  xplorer2k

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra forward slash in the first line of your try:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "//tmp/test1.txt");
```

should be:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/tmp/test1.txt");
```